# Determine private key format

Tags: rsa, digital-signature, private-key, file-format, xml-signature

I have been given a private key to use in signature. The private key is not very secret, only used locally. The problem is, that I don't know that in which format it is.

It doesn't have separate begin and end rows. It's in one line, base64 encoded, 2284 letters long (longer than regular x.509 that I have seen before). I got it with some other variables as well including:

- seed
- id
- compatibility

In the beginning of the id, there's urn:uuid:, before the key value.

Any clues what it could be?

I tried to use the key with node module xmlCrypto, but got some errors:

> Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

Comment: That lenth is probably RSA. I don't know if xmlCrypto (or your use) knows to de-b64 before ASN.1, but to be sure try `openssl base64 -d -A <inputfile | openssl asn1parse inform -d` and see if that gives an error or looks like PKCS#1 (rfc3447) or PKCS#8 (rfc5208). If it's not ASN.1, I'd try PGP (rfc4880); after that there are many possibilities so I would ask the source rather than wasting a lot of time. PS: no X.509 format contains a privatekey; SPKI if used separately (as Java does) is a publickey which is usually much shorter than private for RSA but only slightly for DSA or ECDSA.

Comment: I would need to convert that key to a pem format. Any clue how I could do it?

Comment: Where did you get the file from (ask the one)? Is it used by any software (reverse engineer the loading mechanism)?

Comment: *If* the data encoded by the base64 is one of the privatekey formats for which a PEM type is defined (TTBOMK PKCS1, PKCS8, OpenSSH-new, or PGP), you can convert it by breaking the base64 into lines of length 64 and adding BEGIN and END lines with the correct type, and maybe (for PGP) a few other things. But first **you have to know what format it is**. I gave you suggestions for the few easiest ones; try those first. Or post the first 40 chars, which encodes the first 30 bytes which should be enough to identify the likely formats I can think of.